# Interact with an interactive shell script on python

Tags: python, interactive-shell

I have an interactive shell application on windows.
I would like to write a python script that will send commands to that shell application and read back responses.
However i want to do it interactively, i.e. i want the shell application to keep running as long the python script is.

I have tried

```
self.m_process subprocess.Popen(path_to_shell_app,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
```

and then using stdin and stdout to send and recieve data.
it seems that the shell application is being opened but i can't communicate with it.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to look what subprocess.PIPE means

Comment: How do you use the stdin/stdout? The documentation says: ***Warning** Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.*

Answer (score 3):

There is a module that was built just for that: [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/).  To use, `import pexpect`, and then use `process = pexpect.spawn(myprogram)` to create new subprocesses, and use `process.expect(mystring)` or `process.expect_exact(mystring)` to search for prompts, or to get responses.  `process.send(myinput)` and `process.sendline(myinput)` are used for sending information to the subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

Next you should use [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

```
stdout, stderr = self.m_process.communicate(input=your_input_here)
```

From the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module documentation

> ***Popen.communicate(input=None)***
>   Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.
>   Wait for process to terminate. The optional input argument should be a
>   string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be
>   sent to the child.
>
> communicate() returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).
>
> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to
>   create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything
>   other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE
>   and/or stderr=PIPE too.